# Cannot read property 'jwtoken' of undefined

Tags: mern

here I generate the token at backend in express
..............

```js
router.post("/login",async(req,res)=>{
    const {email,password}=req.body;
    if(!email || !password){
        return res.status(401).send({error:"please filled the data properly"});
    }
    try {
        const loginUser=await User.findOne({email:email});
        if(!loginUser){
            return res.status(400).send({error:"not found"});
        }
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password,loginUser.password);    
        if(isMatch){
            const token=await loginUser.generateToken();
            res.cookie("jwtoken",token,{
                expires:new Date(Date.now()+15000000),
                httpOnly:true,
                //secure:true  //it is applicable when we use https method
            })
            console.log(token);
            res.send({message:"login success"});
        }else{
            res.status(400).send({error:"please enter correct data"})
        }
          
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})
```

[the token is create when i login in brouser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki82y.png)

here is the about page (react)
...................

```
const verifyPage=async()=>{
    try{
        const res=await fetch('/about',{
            method:"GET",
            headers:{
                Accept:"application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            credentials:"include"
        });
        const data=await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        
        if(!res.status===200){
            const err=new Error(res.error);
            throw err;
        }
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        history.push("/login");
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    verifyPage();
},[])
```

.............

here I verify the token
...........

```
router.get("/about",Authentication,(req,res)=>{
res.send(req.rootUser);
})
```

........
The authentication page
............

```js
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User=require("../models/shegma")

const Authentication=async (req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        const token=req.cookies.jwtoken;
        console.log(token)
        const verifyToken=jwt.verify(token,process.env.TOKENID);
        console.log(verifyToken);
        const rootUser=await User.findOne({_id:verifyToken._id,"tokens.token":token})
        if(!rootUser){throw new Error("user not found")}
        req.token=token;
        req.rootUser=rootUser;
        req.userID=rootUser._id;
        next();
    }catch(err){
        res.status(401).send("no token found");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
module.exports=Authentication;
```

..........

here is the error
......

TypeError: Cannot read property 'jwtoken' of undefined
at Authentication (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\middleware\Authentication.js:6:33)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Answer (score 4):

At first, you need to install **cookie-parser** inside your server folder

```
npm i cookie-parser
```

Then, require **cookie-parser** inisde that *.js* file where you have initialized express

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
```

After this, below `const app = express();` just write

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Here is the full code:-

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: I forgot app.use(cookieParser). thnks

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to be parsing the cookies on the incoming request anywhere in your express code?

The `req.cookies` object being `undefined` leads me to believe you may not be parsing the request for cookies or that the parsing is not happening before the `Authentication` handler is called.

For reference: [express cookie-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
const router = express.Router()

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
router.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).